# How to remove console from windows program compiled with g++?

Tags: c++, windows, g++, mingw

So I found online you need to put the flags `-Wl,-subsystem,windows` when compiling with g++ on Windows to hide the console. But I get an error and I can't find any documentation online since the minGW website isn't available so I have no idea how to find a fix.

This is the error I get

```
+ ... gramming\SDL2MinGW\SDL2-2.0.14\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib -w -Wl,-subsyst ...
+                                                                 ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At line:1 char:180
+ ... L2MinGW\SDL2-2.0.14\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows  ...
+                                                                 ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
```

The full command if needed :
`g++ .\01_hello_SDL.cpp -IC:\C++Programming\SDL2MinGW\SDL2-2.0.14\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2 -LC:\C++Programming\SDL2MinGW\SDL2-2.0.14\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -o 01_hello_SDL`

Comment: Try using `-mwindows` instead of `-Wl,-subsystem,windows`

Comment: For those interested I foud out that the culprit was me not knowing that in powershell you have to write "-Wl,-subsystem,windows" with the quotes or else the powershell shell thinks it's an array